# Convert from csv file to an array of specific columns chosen by column name

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am new to nodejs and try to write a program which read a csv file and can select data from csv_file by columns names and convert them into arrays.

**I figured how to read the csv file and convert the columns into arrays(Thanks internet), but the columns are selected by the index number rather than the names.**

code:

```
var csv = require('csv');
var csv_obj = csv();

function Column_data(signal_name, signal_type, initial_value, minimum, maximum  ) {
    this.signal_name = signal_name;
    this.signal_type = signal_type;
    this.initial_value = initial_value;
    this.minimum = minimum;
    this.maximum = maximum;
};

var csv_data = [];

csv_obj.from.path('../data_files/Signals_Info.csv).to.array(function (data) {
    for (var row = 0; row < data.length; index++) {
        csv_data.push(new Column_data(data[row][0], data[row][1], data[row][2], data[row][3], data[row][4]));
    }
    console.log(csv_data);
});
```

**Here I'm using index values 1, 2, 3 to access columns 1, 2 and 3 in my csv. I want to be able to access columns by name rather than by index number because index can change.**

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: how to do this; "From csv file to an array of specific columns chosen by column name." CODE:   

csv_data.push(new Column_data(data[index][0], data[index][1], data[index][2]));        

here I'm using 1, 2, 3 index values to access the columns 1, 2 and 3. I want to be able to access columns by name rather than the index numbers.

Comment: @RohandeepSingh Is the `csv` you're requiring in your sample code an existing npm module, or is it one you've written? I ask because there is an existing package on npm called `csv`, and it already has the option to turn each row into an object keyed by column headers. If, however, `csv` is a module you've written, and you're asking how to get your module to do the same thing, that's a different question.

Comment: @Tex The one I'm using is the pre-existing one. I will look into how I can use it. I was starting to think of other solutions as Gatsby mentioned there is no what of accessing columns by its name. I was thinks of reading just the first line from the csv and just indexing columns I need by finding where they exist in the the comma seperated values.

Comment: @RohandeepSingh What confuses me is that the npm package named `csv` is not a function, so I can't tell which package you're actually using. If you tell us which package you're actually using, we may be able to help you figure out the correct configuration. It's also not difficult to do on your own, in case the package you've chosen to use doesn't support that feature out of the box.

Comment: @Tex its just called csv. I am super new to js and I'm just trying to put things together. I came  across require('csv') while searching for how to read a csv file in nodejs

Answer (score 2):

The following code gives you two options. One is using the 4.0.0 version of the [csv library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv) (`npm install csv`), the other is doing it by hand. Both return the same results given the sample input included below:

```
const csv = require('csv')

const data = `One,Two,Three
1,2,3
4,5,6`

// Using the csv library:
csv.parse(
  data,
  { columns: true },
  (err, result) => console.log(result)
)


// Doing it manually:
const rowToObject = (headers, cells) =>
  headers.reduce(
    (acc, header, i) => {
      acc[header] = cells[i]
      return acc
    },
    {}
  )

const csvToObjects = file => {
  const [headerRow, ...dataRows] = file.split('\n')
  const headers = headerRow.split(',')
  return dataRows.map(
    row => rowToObject(headers, row.split(','))
  )
}

console.log(csvToObjects(data))

// both options output [{One:1,Two:2,Three:3},{One:4,Two:5,Three:6}]
```

You can see both of these running in this [runkit](https://runkit.com/kurtmilam/5bf316170791610012a37ae4) - apologies, I'm not able to run StackOverflow snippets in my browser at this time.

Here I'll mention a third option: It seems you're using an older version of the `csv` package. In addition to `csv().from.path(path).to.array(options, callback)`, the module also offers a `to.object(options, callback)` [method](https://github.com/adaltas/node-csv/blob/44b9541f7767e13ff6f3cc7f35ed358e2757fcee/src/to.coffee#L258), but I'm having trouble finding the documentation on the older version (and don't even know exactly which version you're currently using, which makes things even more difficult).

Comment: Are one two and three column names in the data.csv file or are they the names that you are assigning to columns in the program.

Comment: And I really appreciate your effort in trying to help me. I could do this very easily in python, but I'm trying to learn some js. I hope you don't mind if some of my questions are too trivial.

Comment: @RohandeepSingh `One,Two,Three` are taken from the first row of the csv input. Don't worry about asking simple questions. I may need to ask your help on some Python in the future ;) Make sure you read the update I just posted to my answer. It seems you're using an older version of the `csv` package. That version probably has a way to do what you want, but I haven't found the documentation for it.

Comment: csv version is '6.4.1'. I think your solution might just do the trick. Now I'm thinking of what to use to open the CSV file. I found 'fs' is commonly used to read files, but the csv(); that I found specific for handling csv files doesn't seem to be working. It turns out csv() is not a thing apparently for this module, hence the syntax errors. I'll simply try using the 'fs' for finding the indexes, which is data = read the file using fs. Do you have a better suggestion in how I should handle the csv file.

Comment: Pretty sure 6.4.1 is your npm version and not the version of csv.  Use `npm list csv` to find the version of csv you have installed - my guess is 4.0.0. fs is the built-in node filesystem module, but I don't know what version of node you're on. You'll find plenty of fs-related questions here on SO, but feel free to ask if you get stuck.

Comment: you are right its 4.0.0. I used npm -v csv before and thats when it gave me 6.4.1. oops

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to access the columns by the column_names. When the csv is read, it's just all comma-separated. Instead, you can change the csv output to be read by the column names, like -

```
csv_obj.from.path('../data_files/Signals_Info.csv).to.array(function (data) {
    csv_data['signal_name'] = [];
    csv_data['signal_type'] = [];
    csv_data['initial_value'] = [];
    for (var index = 1; index < data.length; index++) {
        csv_data['signal_name'].push(data[index][0]);
        csv_data['signal_type'].push(data[index][1]);
        csv_data['initial_value'].push(data[index][2]);
        ...
    }
    console.log(csv_data);
});
```

Comment: The issue here is that the index number can change. signal_name could be at index 3 in another file. That's the reason I'm looking to see if its possible to read the columns by name rather than the index numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Papaparse](https://www.papaparse.com/)

and making a reader function like this first -

```
function reader (csv) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            if (csv) {
                parser(csv, {
                ...config,  // . this could be as you want it to - read the docs
                complete:(response) => resolve(response.data),
                error:(error) => reject(error),
             })
          }
        })
     }
contents = reader(csv)
csv_obj = contents.map((row) => ({
signal_name: row[0],
signal_type: row[1], 
initial_value: row[2],
minimum: row[3],
maximum: row[4],

        }))
```